# PSPing doesn't work with smb port 445

Tags: smb, pstools

I am trying to use PSPing to test a storage hostname and smb port 445:

```
psping -l 60k <storage_hostname>:445
```

I immediately got the results as below. No packets were sent. I can access the SMB share so the port and DNS must be working. I tested on a different system with a different SMB storage and got the same results. Please help.

```
TCP latency test connecting to 10.135.10.68:445: Connected
9 iterations (warmup 5) sending 61440 bytes TCP latency test:   0%
The specified network name is no longer available.

TCP roundtrip latency statistics (post warmup):
  Sent = 0, Size = 61440, Total Bytes: 0,
  Minimum = 0.00ms, Maximum = 0.00ms, Average = 0.00ms
```

Comment: It seems to think you're trying to do a TCP latency test instead of a TCP ping test, but TCP latency tests require that you run PsPing in server mode on the target IP address and TCP port (which would require that you first disable your SMB server process on the target machine, in order to free up port 445 so PsPing can use it). Latency tests also seem to require a `-n count` parameter according to the documentation. If you only wanted a TCP ping test, try omitting the `-l 60k` argument.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to test latencies. The target is Isilon storage so I can't  run PsPing in server mode from it. I see some articles use port 445 as examples to check SMB storage so not sure why it is not working on my systems. Could it be blocked by Windows firewall as no packets were sent out? If I remove -l 60k, it works but I think it is ICMP ping instead? I need to test the latencies with 64KB and 512KB sizes.